# Worksheet.Change dows not work when I have two excel files open

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, my code does not work when i have one more excel file open at the same time. In my first file I have this code in sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
Call Module1.simpleRegex
End If

End Sub
```

If I close the other workbook this works just fine. I tried adding workbooks().Activate but it didn't work.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Range` is unqualified. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Module1.simpleRegex
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work if there is another file open. It is just like it doesn't notice that I change the cell value because the workbook isn't activated and therefore it doesn't automatically run the Sub..

Comment: So how is the cell changing if the workbook isn't active? By linked formula or code? Because you couldn't manually change a non-active sheet.

Comment: That's the weird part, I manually paste material into cell A1.. But somehow it doesn't work when another file is open.. I'm so confused.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "workbook isn't activated"? How can you paste data manually without activating the workbook?

Comment: Well, I don't really know.. It probably is activated because as you say, I manually change the sheet. It  just feels like something is up when it doesn't recognize when I change the value (when another workbook is open). Thanks for your help though D_Bester! I'll keep looking at my code and try to figure something out.

Comment: Just to be clear: the code is in Book1 and you're changing the worksheet in Book1? Or are you changing the other workbook?

Comment: Yes, the code is in the same worksheet and workbook that I'm changing!

Comment: That's odd. I'm not sure why that's occurring.

Comment: I've noticed now that the problem only occurs when I close my program and let the other excel file open (which I want). But when I open my program and try to run the Sub it doesn't work any longer.

Comment: Does your second file have *Application.EnableEvents = False* anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The problem was that when I closed my excel file and had another open; the it didn't close my VBA worbook. And when I opened it again it showed 2 of the same workbook.

I googled the problem and found out that some add-ins can be the problem. I disabled some unwanted add-ins and now it works..